# Is there a web crawler the support javascript execution

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-crawler

Scrapy is a good crawler, but it lacks javascript support.

I would like an open source crawler, better written in python, which could support javascript execution, any suggestions?

Comment: tampermonkey and greasemonkey have both worked out very well for me...

Comment: tampermonkey and greasemonkey are both javascript add-ons for browsers, I would like a crawler that supports javascript execution.

Comment: maybe we misunderstood. i use tampermonkey to scour HTML pages on any site, find any contained links to other pages, and download the unique found pages to a folder on my local computer. Userscripts are nice because unlike back-end solutions, they pull in all the ajax and API data before locally saving the document...

Comment: @dandavis Would you be willing to share your tampermonkey script?

Answer (score 0):

Try selenium, which can inject into browser directly and supports many browsers/WebKit including:  Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, PhantomJS.

Notes:
- Firefox is recommended which should be supported without installing additional webdriver. And there a powerful plugin which can generate code automatically: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/
- Full webdriver list can be found at:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html
- Code examples can be found at:  http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html